# JavaScript href toString() Checking if string is empty not giving desired results

Tags: javascript, html, css, href, tostring

I'm checking if the href is empty and if so, then the JavaScript `if statement`

`if ((ext_url_1).toString() != "") {`

should not run its commands.

But so far whether the `href` is empty or not, the `if statement` still runs the commands which sets the `<tr>` to `display: block`.

By default the `<tr>` is set to `display: none` in the css style.

The JavaScript should only set the `<tr>` to `display: block` if the `href` is not empty.

I have to use JavaScript, not jquery.

Do you see any problem with the code?

```
<style>
#externaldocTR1 {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<tr id="externaldocTR1">
  <td>
    <img id="externaldocImg1" src="pdf.gif"> <a id="externaldocURL1" href="">document</a>
    <span id="externaldocExt1"></span>
  </td>
</tr>


<script>

function file_get_ext(filename)
{
return typeof filename != "undefined" ? filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".")+1, filename.length).toLowerCase() : false;
}

var ext_url_1 = document.getElementById("externaldocURL1").href;
var ext_url_2 = document.getElementById("externaldocURL2").href;
var ext_url_3 = document.getElementById("externaldocURL3").href;

var ext_1 = file_get_ext(ext_url_1);
var ext_2 = file_get_ext(ext_url_2);
var ext_3 = file_get_ext(ext_url_3);

var icon_pdf = "pdf.gif";
var icon_word = "word.gif";
var icon_excel = "excel.png";
var icon_img = "jpg.png";

var src_1 = document.getElementById("externaldocImg1");
var src_2 = document.getElementById("externaldocImg2");
var src_3 = document.getElementById("externaldocImg3");


    if ((ext_url_1).toString() != "") {
    document.getElementById("externaldocTR1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("externaldocExt1").innerHTML = " (" + (ext_1).toUpperCase() + ")";
      if (ext_1 == "pdf") { ( (src_1).src = icon_pdf); }
      else if (ext_1 == "DOC" || ext_1 == "DOCX" || ext_1 == "RTF") { ( (src_1).src = icon_word); }
      else if (ext_1 == "XLS" || ext_1 == "XLSX" || ext_1 == "CSV") { ( (src_1).src = icon_excel); }
      else if (ext_1 == "JPG" || ext_1 == "JPEG" || ext_1 == "GIF" || ext_1 == "PNG") { ( (src_1).src = icon_img); }
      else { ( (src_1).src = "");
      }
    }


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather than try to fetch the `href` property of element by doing

```
var ext_url_1 = document.getElementById("externaldocURL1").href;
```

try

```
var ext_url_1 = document.getElementById("externaldocURL1").getAttribute("href");
```

since this href property [may not be supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/href#Browser_compatibility) on all browsers

Comment: Thanks man! I've been working on this for 2 days and all I needed was to use .getAttribute("href"); instead of .href;

Comment: to be clear, using the getAttribute method will be supported on all browsers?

Comment: @Mike yes, getAttribute has been there since ages :)

Comment: thank you! so do I even need to use `if ((ext_url_1).toString() != "")` Do I need to convert the href to string first?